# Helper function(or variable or..?) for versioned classes

Tags: vb.net

I'm working on a project where the data types will most likely change over time. For instance, currently the student class only has the name and ID but say next week I might have to add hash for a library computer password or whatever.

I decided to go with a structure like this:

```
Public Class Student
    Public Class V1
        Public Name as String
        Public ID as Int64
    End Class
End Class
```

When new things come along or go away, I make a new class "V2" that will implement the changes and I will also make a conversion function between each of the versions so when the student object gets loaded from the database(probably mongodb) and it happens to be the old version, it automatically gets converted to the new version.

It occurred to me though, that it would help if I could make a helper function in the Student class to get the latest version so I could do something like this:

```
Dim a as New Student.Latest
```

instead of

```
Dim a as new Student.V1
```

which would force me to replace the V1 with V2 in the entire code every time there is an update

I could do it by creating a class called Latest and inheriting the latest version but then it would store the student version class as Latest and I'd lose all ability to differentiate between them. In c++ I could just #define Latest V1 and it would create the object as the class defined but I don't know of any such functionality in vb.net. Does anybody have an idea how to do this?

Comment: That whole concept seems pretty diabolical to me.

Comment: Why would you do this?  From your description you will only be *adding* properties/database columns.  If you are using a good ORM (like Entity Framework) then adding these would for the most part constitute non-breaking changes.  It sounds a lot like you are way over-thinking things.

Comment: The VB equivalent of your `#define` would be `Imports Latest = Student.Latest` but as others have suggested it's quite evil.